# Locking all the strings in a collection

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have a collection of strings which must be locked upon by a thread for computing some information. These strings are nothing but unique entities which must be handled by only one thread at a time. Any thread other than the current thread trying to acquire lock on any of these entities in the collection must wait for the current thread to complete its execution and release the lock on the collection. Two entirely different collection containing different strings can be worked upon by two different threads concurrently. I am stuck how to implement this. I tried googling. But all I found was how to lock a single string not many strings. Any idea would be helpful.

For example,
Thread one is working on apple, oranges and bananas.
Thread two wants to works on apple and peaches.

Thread two must wait until Thread one releases the lock.

**Update:**
   Instead of looking upon the lock literally think of it as a permit to use the entity. For example, if you need to use apple, you must acquire permission. The thread must block until it gets permission for all the entities in its collection.

Let met put it in this way. Thread1 [apples, oranges, bananas] seeks permission to use the entities in the collection to a Manager. Lets assume the manager gave permission to Thread1. If another thread Thread2 [apples, peaches] seeks permission, the Manager should not give permission since permission for `apples` is already owned by Thread1 and Thread2 must be blocked. Once Thread1 tells the manager that it has completed its work, the Manager can give permission to Thread2. Meanwhile, if another thread Thread3 [guava, pineapple] seeks permission, the Manager should not block it and grant permission readily.

Comment: Can you copy the strings? Then lock access to the collection, copy the relevant strings, release lock, let the second thread access the collection.

Comment: The requirement you're describing is problematic, since whichever way you implement that, you're exposing yourself to potential (and even quite certain) deadlocks.

Comment: No @Absurd-Mind. I din't mean literally locking the string object. I just wanted to lock the name so that no other thread can use it. If it wants to use the name, thread must own the lock.

Comment: @eitanfar Could you please explain how deadlock occurs here??

Comment: Use a `Map<String,Lock>` and try to lock the required resources, but you can't wait that a lock gets released. Example: Thread1 wants `B` and `C` and starts locking `B`. Now Thread2 comes along and wants `C` and `B`, and starts locking `C`. T1 waits for `C` and T2 waits for `B`. Classic Deadlock.

Comment: See the last comment by @Absurd-Mind for a dead lock example like I was talking about

Comment: Yeah I got it. But there must some way to implement this. I need a start.

Comment: Yes, split the data in a way that you don't need locks, or at least need fewer. But for that you have to describe your problem a bit better.

Comment: No I cannot split the data because they must be worked as a whole. Think of the lock like a permit to access the entity rather than literally considering it as a lock.

Comment: Then why do you need multiple locks?

Comment: They are not multiple locks. A single lock indicating that all the entities are owned by the current thread. If another thread wants to own any of the entities in the collection, it must wait for the lock to be released by the current thread.

Comment: I don't get it. Is this what you are looking for? `synchronized(data) { work(data); }`. data may be a `List<String>`. In this example only one thread can enter work(data); at a time.

Comment: I have updated my example in a better way. Hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

Instead of operating on many lock I would choose one synchronized storage of "locked" Strings.
That would hugely simplify synchronization.
Something like that:

```
private final Set<String> elementsInProgress = new HashSet<String>(); // not thread-safe, accessed only from blocks synchronized on it

    public void process(Collection<String> input) throws InterruptedException {
        for (String stringToProcess : input) {
            synchronized (elementsInProgress) {
                while (elementsInProgress.contains(stringToProcess)) {
                    elementsInProgress.wait();
                }
                elementsInProgress.add(stringToProcess);
            }

            doProcess(stringToProcess);

            synchronized (elementsInProgress) {
                elementsInProgress.remove(stringToProcess);
                elementsInProgress.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
    private void doProcess(String s){/* ... */}
```

The code snippet is untested, btw )

Comment: As far as i understood the problem, `stringToProcess` is not the data to process, it's rather the Lock-Object on which to look, each thread will need a couple of locks to work properly.

Comment: I need to work on the entire collection of strings. Not in a loop fashion.

Comment: Well, If you're dealing with collections there has to be a loop somewhere. Maybe you can post your single-thread-model code and we'll help you with parallelization / synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

How about starting with `guava-libraries`

```
import com.google.common.collect.Interners;
import com.google.common.collect.Interner;
```

Then create an an interner.  Weak references are OK b/c it's the particular instance that holds the lock.  You could use a ConcurrentMap (careful to use putIfAbsent) to do your interning, but...

```
Interner<String> namedLocks = Interners.newWeakInterner();
```

Then the client threads can simply use synchronized. I'm using `Callable` to represent the work.

```
public <T> void doWork(String name, Callable<T> work) {
  synchronized(namedLocks.intern("name")) {
     return work.call();
  }
}
```

This will work if Thread 1 (apple, oranges, bananas) and Thread 2 (apple, peaches) can work on (for example) "oranges" and "peaches" concurrently.  The 'work' variable in this case represents the work of 'oranges' independently.

If Thread 2 must wait until Thread 1 is done with all three items before starting any of its own, then it's a bit more complex but still manageable.  The 'work' in this case represents 'apple+oranges+bananas'.

```
public <T> T doWork(List<String> names, Callable<T> work) {
  // important to avoid deadlocks
  names = new ArrayList<>(names);
  Collections.sort(names);
  return doWorkInternal(names.iterator());
}
private <T> T doWorkInternal(Iterator<String> names, Callable<T> work) { 
  if(names.hasNext()) {
    synchronized(namedLocks.intern(names.next())) {
       return doWorkInternal(names, work);
    }
  } else { // no more locks to acquire
    return work.call();
  }
}
```

In the above, you're acquiring each lock in sorted order (important for deadlock) as you recurse down the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FruitRunnable implements Runnable {
    // this is the actual lock
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    // here we store which objects are currently used
    private static final Set<String> usedObjects = new HashSet<String>();

    // these are the objects a thread will need
    private final String[] neededObjects;

    public FruitRunnable(String... neededObjects) {
        this.neededObjects = neededObjects;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        acquireLock(neededObjects);

        // between these two methods we can assure that there is
        // no other thread working on our resources
        work();

        // important! release the resources afterwards!
        releaseLock(neededObjects);
    }

    private void work() {
        System.out.println("working: " + Arrays.toString(neededObjects));
        try {
            // work of 10 seconds
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void acquireLock(String[] fruits) {
        // go into lock
        synchronized (lock) {
            // loop until we can acquire our resources
            boolean success = false;
            while (!success) {
                success = true;
                for (String s : fruits) {
                    if (usedObjects.contains(s)) {
                        // too bad this fruit is already in use
                        success = false;
                    }
                }

                // on success add all used fruits to the usedObjects Set and return
                if (success) {
                    for (String s : fruits) {
                        usedObjects.add(s);
                    }
                    return;
                }

                // if we had no success we will wait until some other thread
                // releases fruits
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void releaseLock(String[] fruits) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // release the fruits and notify the other threads to re-check
            for (String s : fruits) {
                usedObjects.remove(s);
            }
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // starting the threads from your example
        new Thread(new FruitRunnable("apple", "oranges", "bananas")).start();
        new Thread(new FruitRunnable("apple", "peaches")).start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        new Thread(new FruitRunnable("guava", "pineapple")).start();
    }
}
```

Find some comments on how it works in code.